# Find files without certain permissions

Tags: linux, file, search

How do I get the name of the first directory (alphabetically) of / that has no read permission for other?

I've tried,

```
find / -type d -perm -o=w+x | sort

find / type d -perm 773 | sort
```

I know its probably something really simple but I just cannot get my brain to figure it out!

Comment: `find / -type d -perm 0773 | sort` (confirm the `3` which is an odd world permission)

Answer (score 2):

It seems it can be as easy as this.

```
find / -type d -not -perm -o=r -print | sort
```

The `-perm -o=r` matches any file that *has* read permissions for “others”.  The `-not` prefix negates that. The other tests you have already figured out yourself.